# Where is the up-to-date, full pstricks documentation?

Tags: pstricks, documentation

The contents of my /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/*pdf is this (sorted by time):

```
 189902 May 30  2009 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/test-pst.pdf
 898183 May 30  2009 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/pst-user.pdf
5367012 May 30  2009 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/pstricks-doc.pdf
 133777 May 30  2009 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/pst-news05.pdf
  85767 Feb 12  2010 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/pst-news06.pdf
   6433 Feb 12  2010 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/pst-doc.pdf
  89829 Sep  8  2011 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/pst-news11.pdf
  99091 Dec 22  2012 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/pst-news12.pdf
  89659 Dec  9  2013 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/pst-news09.pdf
 103548 Dec 31  2013 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/pst-news13.pdf
  77050 Jun 30  2015 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/pst-news14.pdf
 284322 Nov 16  2015 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/pst-news15.pdf
  81896 Jan  6  2018 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/pst-news17.pdf
 572968 Jan  6  2018 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/pst-news10.pdf
  74212 Jan  7  2019 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/pst-news18.pdf
  47967 May 12  2019 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/pst-news16.pdf
 320406 Sep 20  2020 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/pst-news20.pdf
 129526 Sep 24  2021 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/pst-news21.pdf
  71977 Sep 25  2021 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/pst-news19.pdf
 131821 Sep 25  2021 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/pst-news08.pdf
```

As we see, the full-documentation files (pst-user.doc and pstricks-doc.pdf) are all around 13 years old.  Is any newer full documentation available somewhere, or do we have (say, in case of an error message, in my case „dimension too large“ for an old document that got complied 12 years ago but doesn't get compiled any longer) to plow through all of the old documentation and all the news?  `texdoc pstricks` shows the old `pstricks-doc.pdf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main documentation of the *base* system: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pstricks-base
is from 2007 because the sources of this documentation were lost around
2010. Only fragments of the sources from the very first beginning around 1992 are available. All additions and code changes are listed in the news papers: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/base/doc

All other documentations are up-to-date, whatever this means ... ;-)
https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib

Comment: Wow. I didn't know that the old sources are mostly gone. That explains it. Such a loss is sad, anyway.

Comment: Out of curiosity, has anyone tried to ask and of the Internet-connected AI generators, such as ChatGPT, for the old sources as of 2007? They have the Internet as their data base, so chances are that if the sources are still available anywhere, they could be retrieved.

Answer (score 4):

As you are using /usr/share you probably have a older texlive.

texlive 2022 uses this document

https://texdoc.org/serve/pstricks/0

dated 25th July 2003

and

https://texdoc.org/serve/pstricks-add/0

Dated November 2021

In general, for any package you can start from the links in the ctan catalogue

https://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks-base

Comment: The first document has time-travelled it seems :)

Comment: @Marijn fortuately I didn't break the flux capacitor and could travel back

Comment: Though I do have a stock Debian TeXLive, your https://texdoc.org/serve/pstricks/0 is the same as my `pstricks-doc.pdf` (5367012 bytes, internal date `Wed May  3 11:34:51 2006 CEST`). Your second link doesn't cover all the pstricks, but only the additional macros. For example, `\psaxes` is not documented there. “Package documentation” from your third link points to the same `pst-user.pdf` as in my stock installation (898183 bytes, internal date `Sun Dec 23 11:24:19 2007 CET`). Or is your claim that these three documents *together* cover everything, including the news of the recent two decades?

Comment: @AlbertNash That's the core doc https://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/ lists updates for all the bits such as pst-math all of which have their own doc,